# Should I tokenize line breaks to separate statements or worry about this on the parser?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, tokenize, lexer

I built a basic tokenizer in PHP, right now it parses something similar to javascript albeit semicolons are not needed to separate statements.

```
a = 1
b = a + 1
echo b

T_IDENTIFIER  a
T_EQUAL       =
T_NUMBER      1
T_IDENTIFIER  b
T_EQUAL       =
T_IDENTIFIER  a
T_NUMBER      1
T_IDENTIFIER  echo
T_IDENTIFIER  b
```

This is my first compiler so I'm not sure if I'm ready to move on to parsing. I'm ignoring line breaks on the lexer so there is no separator between statements, but in my DSL line-breaks can be used as an alternative to semicolons.

My question is, should I start worrying about separating statements on the lexer or should I modify my tokenizer to include line breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are the langauge designer, the choice is up to you. I find languages that treat newlines as special awkward and languages that sometimes treat newlines as special (Scala, Haskell, Icon) annoying. Depending on the details of your syntax it might be easy to separate statements in the parser as is done in Euclid and Turing. For example

```
<Statement> ::= <Var> = <Expression>
              | echo <Expression>
              | { Block }
              | if <Expression> <Statement> else <Statement>
              | while <Expression <Statement>
<Block> ::= <Statement> <Block>
         |  <Declaration> <Block>
         |
```

There is no ambiguity so far.  If you are careful about the other nonterminals there needn't be any ambiguity.

Comment: I'm thinking on using line breaks as an alternative to separate statements. Would that be awkward or annoying?

Comment: Do you mean as an alternative to semicolons?  The awkward part comes from the problem that sometimes we have a long statement and for readability reasons we want to put it on multiple lines.  Either you give up on that or you have to introduce some complication to allow exceptions.  E.g. in Fortran 77 you'd put a nonblank character in column 6 to indicate that a line is a continuation of the previous line. Another example: in C you use a backslash to indicate that a macro definition is continued on the next line.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. I just wanted the syntaxis be simple and been looking into python. I'll make semicolons mandatory between statements. How does python solve this issue? Just curious

Comment: @Liso22 Python treats line breaks as statement separators, except in two circumstances. There's an explicit line continuation character (`\` preceding a newline means the newline is ignored), though it's discouraged in style guides - IMHO you should ignore it exists. The preferred way to make statements span lines is to put parens/brackets around an expression such that the newline is inside the parens/brackets, as *all* whitespace inside parens/brackets is ignored. This kind of stuff is documented in the [language reference](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/).

Comment: I left Python out of my list, as I hadn't used it.  Its rules sound like they may escape being awkward or annoying.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "semicolons are not needed to separate statements", you imply in fact that "line breaks are necessary to separate statements".

You will ease your work by generating some T_ENDOFINSTRUCTION in your flow of tokens. Your parser will use it separate statements.

Comment: Why does "semicolons are not needed to separate statements" imply "line breaks are necessary to separate statements". Maybe all that is needed to separate statements is whitespace or even nothing at all. E.g. in Euclid `a:=(b)c:=d` is two statements separated by nothing at all.

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell: ok, I see your point. By the way, ECMAScript does not require the semicoma neither, but honestly it really does not help readability in my opinion. It makes the parser more complex as well. This capability (having no separator between statements) is very prone to error in my experience.

Comment: It depends on the details of the language.  I wrote a lot of code in Turing, which follows the Euclid approach and never had a problem.  I've written a little bit of Scala and have already run afoul of its rules for inferring where statements end.  The point I wanted to make is that is is possible to design a syntax where statements have no extra terminator or separator token. The Euclid/Turing example goes further to say that it often works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

If line breaks are part of the language (e.g., a statement sometime ends on a line boundary), you should probably produce ENDOFLINE as a token.  This kind of sounds like your case.

If line breaks are always whitespace, the lexer should just eat them as whitespace.

If the line break is *sometimes* useful, sometimes not, (e.g., a block-style THEN clause is introduced by "THEN*newline*", you should probably produce *2* THEN tokens: one which is **THEN** and one which is **THENnewline**.

I wouldn't kill myself worrying about how to get the lexer right on the first try, since they are easy to revise.     Get it sort of right (e.g., use the rule of thumb above), and then get on with writing your parser.   As the parser jells, it will be clear if the lexer has to help more by producing newline or special tokens, and then you can go back and revise it accordingly.

Comment: I added a LINEBREAK token. thanks, I'll see what happens with the parser

Answer (score 0):

I've been designing a language in the last few weeks and made the lexer by hand. My language does not treat NEWLINE as token nor SEMICOLON is needed to identify end of expression. **The expression syntax itself defines when a statement ends**.

This goes well most of the time, but as all statements in my language are also expressions, there are some ambiguities:

**a(b) [method call] vs a \n (b) [two expressions]**: I explicitly require that some tokens aren't preceeded by NEWLINE, '(' is one of them *when used in the context of method call*.

**4-2 [subtraction] vs 4 \n -2 [two expressions]**: Also, binary operators that use the same token as unary operators require that no NEWLINE comes before them.

Other than that, to avoid some mistakes by the user, I explicitely require that if two expressions are on the same line, they must be separated with SEMICOLON. Of course there is no ambiguity involved, it's just to avoid typos going undetected, like:

```
c = a adn b
```

This would understand `a adn b` as a single block that returns **only b**.